# Getting exception as "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Tags: excel

When i am trying to read data from the excel file it giving me error as "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )"
How to resolve this??

My string is

String path = "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Param.xlsx";

---

I have tried both the way but couldn't able to run my script.
I 'm writing java program to read data from the excel file. so for path i used that string but unable to make it happen!
Please help me.

Comment: How are you trying to read data from the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
int i=0;
StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(path, "\\");
while (strToken.hasMoreTokens()) {                  
  i += 1;
  System.out.println(i + ". element: " + strToken.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided so much information so I am trying to guess what you are actually doing. But assuming that you want to open an Excel file in C# then your string is wrong because it contains invalid escape sequences. However, that is easily fixed:

```
String path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Param.xlsx";
```

Notice the `@` in front of the string.

Or you could escape the backslashes in the string:

```
String path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\Param.xlsx";
```